# How to send strings between python and go

Tags: python, sockets, go, server, client

I am trying to understand how to interact with python socket server meant for python socket client but in go

please rewrite python client in go language with same functionality without changing server code, that should be enough for me to understand how to do it

server:

```py
import socket

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 5556

server.bind((host,port))
server.listen()
client, adress = server.accept()
#1
variable1 = client.recv(4096).decode('utf-8')
print(variable1)
#2
client.send("send2".encode('utf-8'))
#3
variable2 = client.recv(4096).decode('utf-8')
print(variable2)
#4
client.send("send4".encode('utf-8'))
```

client:

```py
import socket

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 5556

client.connect((host, port))


#1
client.send("send1".encode('utf-8'))
#2
variable1 = client.recv(4096).decode('utf-8')
print(variable1)
#3
client.send("send3".encode('utf-8'))
#4
variable2 = client.recv(4096).decode('utf-8')
print(variable2)
```

Comment: You must use some sort of protocol to know what the "end" of a message is -- length prefix, newline delimited, etc. Like you said, TCP is a streaming protocol, so there is no such thing as individual messages at that level.

Comment: I edited question a bit so now its easier to understand, I don`t believe that there is no way to accept what python sends if it can accept messages from itself, unfortunately I cant find answers in python socket code as its too complicated for me, and as I wrote in an edited question, the possible solution is to find what delimiter does python socket use when comunicating to itself

Comment: Python does not do anything extra, you just happen to get sends and reads that correspond with incorrect code, but there is nothing ensuring that will always be the case. Send multiple "messages" without a delimiter before reading any, and there is no way to read them separately. Think of the TCP stream like a file, if you write multiple messages to the file with no pre-defined format, how are you going to break them back up again?

Comment: thats the point, I don`t know how, I want to understand how to implement python socket .recv() in go, and I am not bound to net package, I will be more than satisfied if someone already wrote an implementation and published go package on github

Comment: There is nothing different in python's TCP implementation, any behavior difference you see is by chance, not by design. You must use _something_ to delimit messages.

Comment: To rephrase what @JimB explained, TCP does not provide message framing; it considers the two streams a TCP connection transfers as completely opaque streams of bytes. The only guarantee TCP makes about these streams is that these bytes, if at all delivered, are delivered exactly once each, and preserving their relative order. There do exist protocols sitting at the same place in the network stack and preserving message boundaries (SCTP for instance) but TCP is not one of them; implementing this must be the task of the application layer on top of TCP.

Comment: While we're at it, note that Go's `encoding/json.Decoder` is fine with decoding multiple JSON values (usually JSON objects) from a single contiguous stream of bytes. So if you send a sequence of bytes literally reading, say, `{"foo":42}{"bar":12}`, decoding them with the `json.Decoder` would require two calls to its `Decode` method and would produce two objects. Here, there's no explicit delimiter but message framing is implemented by having clear boundaries of each object (which can be thought of as representing a message).

Comment: You could also easily implement text-line-based framing—usually with [`bufio.Scanner`](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#Scanner).

Comment: I considered that bufio.Scanner might be the solution but unfortunately I failed when tried using that because I only started using Go seriously yesterday and only know basics

Comment: Your updated python code shows exactly what I said, there is no message framing added by python, you just do alternating synchronous sends and receives which happens to look like it's working. Your "protocol" here is "wait for a response after each send", but running concurrent processes sending and receiving multiple messages asynchronously will quickly fail. Use some sort of simple protocol to add message framing.

Comment: yes, concurrency is simply not available when you do it like that, and I am well aware of that, I guess it would be better to write a protocol after all because I would eventually need concurrency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close the connection to terminate the stream of data from the server to the client:

```
⋮
client.send("text1".encode('utf-8'))
client.close()
```

Read to EOF in the client program:

```
⋮
message, err := io.ReadAll(conn)                
checkError(err)
fmt.Println(string(message))
```

Comment: technically you made it work as I asked in the question but that works only 1 time so Im going to change the question so its even easier to understand